# I need help about sorting

Tags: java

I want to sort my file's content. My file content is student names,their student no, their class, their grades.These datas are seperated by ";".First I needed to calculate average and letter grade. I've calculated them but i need to write all of the content to another file and the order must be highest grade to lowest grade. What should I do?

```
Example of file content: Index;StdNo;Name;Surname;Average;Letter

Here is what I done by so far:

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class project3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file= new File("Grades.csv");
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            String[] str= new String[16];
            StringTokenizer st;
            String[] index= new String[16];
            String[] stdNo= new String[16];
            String[] name= new String[16];
            String[] surname= new String[16];
            String[] classYear= new String[16];
            String[] midterm= new String[16];
            String[] project= new String[16];
            String[] finalExam= new String[16];
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            for(int i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
                str[i]=scan.nextLine();
                st=new StringTokenizer(str[i],";");
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    index[i]=st.nextToken();
                    stdNo[i]=st.nextToken();
                    name[i]=st.nextToken();
                    surname[i]=st.nextToken();
                    classYear[i]=st.nextToken();
                    midterm[i]=st.nextToken();
                    project[i]=st.nextToken();
                    finalExam[i]=st.nextToken();
                    
                }
                
            }
        
        }
        String[] average= new String[16];
        String[] letter= new String[16];
        
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++) {
            if(i==0) {
                average[i]="Average";
                letter[i]="Letter";
                continue;
            }
            
            average[i]=averageCalculator(midterm[i],project[i],finalExam[i]);
            letter[i]=letterCalculator(averageCalculator(midterm[i],project[i],finalExam[i]));
        }
        File f= new File("Letter.csv");
        try {
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f));
            for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
            pw.println(index[i]+";"+stdNo[i]+";"+name[i]+";"+surname[i]+";"+average[i]+";"+letter[i]);
            pw.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            
        }
        File f1=new File("Ordered.csv");
            PrintWriter pw2=new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f1));
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(f);
        

            
            
            
            
            
            
                
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            
        }
        
            
        
    }
public static String averageCalculator(String midterm, String project, String finalExam) {
    return Double.toString((Double.parseDouble(midterm)*0.3)+(Double.parseDouble(project)*0.3)+(Double.parseDouble(finalExam)*0.4));
}
public static String letterCalculator(String average) {
    String letter="FF";
    if((Double.parseDouble(average) >=90)&&(Double.parseDouble(average) <=100)) {
        letter="AA";
    }
    else if((Double.parseDouble(average) >=85)&&(Double.parseDouble(average) <=89)) {
        letter="BA";
    }
    else if((Double.parseDouble(average) >=75)&&(Double.parseDouble(average) <=84)) {
        letter="BB";
    }
    else if((Double.parseDouble(average) >=70)&&(Double.parseDouble(average) <=74)) {
        letter="CB";
    }
    else if((Double.parseDouble(average) >=60)&&(Double.parseDouble(average) <=69)) {
        letter="CC";
    }
    else if((Double.parseDouble(average) >=55)&&(Double.parseDouble(average) <=59)) {
        letter="DC";
    }
    else if((Double.parseDouble(average) >=50)&&(Double.parseDouble(average) <=54)) {
        letter="DD";
    }
    
    return letter;
}




}
```

Comment: you have created yourself a big headache to allow sorting because you are storing individual student attributes in separate arrays.  You should create some sort of Container class that contains all those attributes, and manipulate/sort that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to model the student data

```
public class Student {
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  ... etc ...
}
```

Instead of reading the data into the arrays, construct a `Student` for each row and add it to a `List`.  So reading your input file results in `List<Student>`.  Then you can execute your calculations on those objects to set the values you want to record in the output file.  Then sort the `List` based on the value you care about.  With the `List` sorted, you can write the data to the output data file.  Moving logic into methods may make your `main` method look something like..

```
List<Student> students = readInputsFile(getInputFile());
calculateStuff(students);
sortByGrade(students);
writeToFile(students, getOutputFile());
```